# How do I setup my router for ros2 humble ubuntu computers to talk to each other on the same network?

Tags: ros2

I've setup two ubuntu 22.04 computers with ros2 humble on the same network using two different routers.

1. When both computers are connected via Wi-Fi to a GL-MT300N-V2 Mini Smart Router, I run a talker on one computer and a listener on the other computer, and it works flawlessly without changing any configuration on the router.
2. When both computers are connected via Wi-Fi to a Netgear Nighthawk AX6 Router, I run a talker on one computer and a listener on the other computer, and it does not work.

Is there any special configuration required on a Wi-Fi router for the middleware of ros2 to work properly and allow communication between two computes to work as it should?

In both scenarios, I did not change anything on the computers other than connecting them to a different router.

I would really appreciate assistance on this.

Comment: In the second scenario do you have by any chance an ethernet cable connected to a different network? Because I've had a problem where ROS2 uses ethernet for communication instead of wifi.

Comment: No.  In both scenarios, the routers were only connected to the two ros2 ubuntu computers via Wi-Fi.  Nothing else was connected to the routers.

Comment: I mean to the computers there should not be any ethernet cable connected, only Wifi.

Comment: Same thing for the computers.  No internet cable is connected to them.

Comment: You can try checking the enabled services in your router, sometimes routes by default doesn't allow some services to run like ssh, tcp, udp etc you'll need to explicitly enable them. You can also check the port forwarding  and NAT settings. If you can't figure out then post the settings here.

Comment: @tomRob - you should *probably* post that as an answer...

Answer (score 0):

I've ordered and installed the more powerful GL-MT3000 Beryl AX3000 WiFi6 Router from GL.iNet.  It works perfectly with ROS2 for the talker-listener use case described above.  I will not investigate this problem further.  I believe I'll be able to do what I want to do with this router going forward.  However, I would still be interested in knowing what configuration is required on any router to make ROS2 work properly.  I cannot believe I'm the only one who's been struggling with this.  Thank you Diego, Tom and Greenonline for your assistance.